# Python pandas - How to create separate lists of duplicates and uniques?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have list of uniques from column ACCOUNTMANAGER and I need to pick sorted duplicates to separate file.

Is it possible to use duplicates or something similar to pick identical column values and save them to separate lists?

Let's say ACCOUNTMANAGER contains list of names `['Jack', 'Jack', 'Dane', 'Jessica', 'Jessica', 'Jessica' ]`. I would like to have jack list of all `Jacks`, `Dane` list oven if one value and list of `Jessicas`. How can I do this using uniques and duplicates? Here is my code:

```py
uniques = df['ACCOUNTMANAGER'].unique()
print(uniques)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dictionary of lists with repeated values is grouping by column and create lists for same column used for grouping:

```
d = df.groupby('ACCOUNTMANAGER')['ACCOUNTMANAGER'].agg(list).to_dict()

print (d['Jack'])
print (d['Dane'])
print (d['Jessica'])
```

In python [string variables are not recommneded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables), but possible e.g. by globals:

```
for n, vals in df.groupby('ACCOUNTMANAGER')['ACCOUNTMANAGER'].agg(list).items():
    globals()[n] =  vals

print (Jessica)
```

Comment: using lines: d = df.groupby('ACCOUNTMANAGER')['ACCOUNTMANAGER'].agg(uniques).to_dict()

print(d)

I get error: TypeError: ndarray() missing required argument 'shape' (pos 1)

Comment: @ErikIlonen - There is `list`, not `uniques`

Comment: that works nicely but how can I pick whole dataframe rows with it and make sepparate lists?

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to rather loop 'ACCOUNTMANAGER' and create separate lists based on the occurrence of list? And I still don't get the whole rows df

Comment: @ErikIlonen - Not understand, what is reason for it?

Comment: @ErikIlonen - `And I still don't get the whole rows df ` Can you be more specific?

Comment: One more thing. This code doesn't print anything for some reason: 
for n, vals in df.groupby('ACCOUNTMANAGER')['ACCOUNTMANAGER'].agg(list).items():
    if vals == uniques[1]:
        print(vals)

Comment: @ErikIlonen - so compare by same value `uniques[1]` ? And never print any value?

Comment: uniques[1] contains equivalent value to 'Jessica' and it prints nothing for some reason

Comment: @ErikIlonen - because in `vals` are `['Jessica', 'Jessica', 'Jessica']`, need compre with `n` like ` if n == uniques[1]`

Comment: Do you have any solution to how to get df rows that are equivalent to those group by sets? Let's say all df rows that are 'Jessica'?

Comment: @ErikIlonen - Use `df[df. ACCOUNTMANAGER == n]`

Comment: @ErikIlonen - What is error? Because there is using [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), so problem something else

Comment: Traceback (most recent...):
  File "/Users/erik.ilonen/Desktop/Projekti_csv_data/Kolmas_testiohjelma/All_clientaccounts_with_auto_invest.py", line 106, in <module>
    print(df[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
erik.ilonen@32-MacBook-Air Kolmas_testiohjelma %

Comment: @ErikIlonen - It means in your code was overwrite original DataFrame, test what return `print (df)` ?

Comment: df prints correctly but with that line of code I get this error:

    df = df['ACCOUNTMANAGER' == n]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: False
erik.ilonen@32-MacBook-Air Kolmas_testiohjelma %

Comment: That was my bad. I changed df.ACCOUNTMANAGER to 'ACCOUNTMANAGER'. It works fine now. Many thanks jezrael and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

If its for only one column, you can do this way as well (using pandas `value_counts`)

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ACCOUNTMANAGER': ['Jack', 'Jack', 'Dane', 'Jessica', 'Jessica', 'Jessica' ]})

>>> df.ACCOUNTMANAGER.value_counts()
Jessica    3
Jack       2
Dane       1
Name: ACCOUNTMANAGER, dtype: int64

>>> for key, value in df.ACCOUNTMANAGER.value_counts().items():
...     print([key] * value)

['Jessica', 'Jessica', 'Jessica']
['Jack', 'Jack']
['Dane']
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I pick whole rows of dataframe while finding occurences?

Comment: With in the `for loop` use a conditional filter on `df` like `new_df = df[df. ACCOUNTMANAGER == key]`. This `new_df` is your selected df with list of rows, for that one key.

If you are going to need rows for each uniue filter then I recommend using `group by` which very cost efficient method. Look for pandas docs for more info. Otherwise this will do !

Comment: Thanks sam as well